# Loops with if function Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, loops, if-statement, matrix

I was wondering if somebody could help me out. I am using the following code:

```
Jan=B
for j=2:12

   if Jan(:,15)=1 ;
       Jan(:,j)=0;
   end
end
```

What I try to do in words, if for every row of column `Jan` is not equal to 1, than all values in the matrix from column 2 to 12 should be equal to 0. If a row in column `Jan` is equal to 1 nothing should happen. I hope I have given enough information. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: The problem is that nothing happens if I run my code

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in the above code.  **Jan(:,15)** will return the 15th column of **Jan**.  This cannot be assigned the value of one in the **if** condition (this should be generating an error?).  Should this be **Jan(:,15)==1**?  But that is wrong too because it will compare a column vector of 15 elements with a single value of one…and so will never evaluate to true (which may explain why nothing is happening if you run the code).  What are your dimensions for **B**?  What problem is the above code trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for responding.. I will try to clarify, Jan(:,15) is column with a month number.. Jan(:,2 to 12) (so from column two to twelve) are forward rates. Now I want to have only the forward rates, column two to twelve, if column 15 is 1. So, nothing happens in a row if column 15 is equal to 1, if column 15 is not equal to 1 is must be zero..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
Jan = randi(3,6,5);    % A sample matrix
Jan =
   1   1   2   3   3
   2   2   3   3   2
   2   2   2   1   2
   1   2   3   1   3
   2   1   2   3   2
   1   2   3   2   2

Jan(Jan(:,4) ~= 1, :) = 0    % You should change 4 with 15
Jan =
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   2   2   2   1   2
   1   2   3   1   3
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
```

`Jan(:,4) ~= 1` returns a vector containing of zeros and ones, where the ones represent the rows where the fourth column is not `1` (`~=` means unequal, while `==` means equal).

`Jan(Jan(:,4) ~= 1, :) = 0` will turn all those rows into zeros (the `:` sign essentially means "everything on this row").

If you want to *remove* the rows, you would do: `Jan(Jan(:,4) ~= 1, :) = []`.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Robert P. thank you very much, this is exactly what I was trying to do, great. Geoff also thank you for you response